# Wondering why this formula works in one cell and not another and if there is any alternative

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, indexing, max

this is the formula in question,

```
=INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C),1)
```

in this form it works perfectly and displays the latest result from that row and column.

```
=INDEX(AA:AA,COUNTA(AA:AA),1)
```

However, the above does not work and just displays blank. Why does the double column identifier ruin it? is there an alternative I can use for these columns?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely you got there an empty cell in that AA column that will offset the result

try this instead:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("AA"&MAX((AA:AA<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, so I gave that a go and got the following error: "Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'AA0.' It is not a valid cell/range reference."

Comment: @Ben fixed, try now

Comment: That worked perfectly! thank you for your time